# Backend Block for frontend in Magento2

Tags: magento2, overrides, frontend, backend

How we can override the backend block for frontend functionality. I am trying to override the following block for my frontend functionality

**Magento\Payment\Block\Adminhtml\Transparent\Form**

Is there any hint or idea?

Thank you,